# How do you check if a user exists in a database table?

Tags: mysql, database, exists

I am trying to find out if the currently logged in user exists in a certain database table. If they already exist, give an error. If they don't I need to add the username and form data to the table. I am new to php and mysql databases. Here is what I have so far for code:

```
//my HTML form, pretty simple.
<form method="post" action="">
<p>Out of Office <input name="onoff" type="checkbox" value="ON"></p>

<p><label>Custom Out of Office Message</label>
<input type="text" name="custommessage" size="30" maxlength="25"/></p>

<p><label>Enter Username</label>
<input type="text" name="username" size="30" maxlength="25"/></p>

<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>

<?php
//I figured if I get the user information from the "b83hi_users" table, I can check it against the field input for "username" in the form above.

$user = JFactory::getUser();

if ($user->username == $_POST['username']) {

    //This checks if the checkbox is marked ON(or off). If it is checked (ON), I want to insert the form data into a table b83hi_out_of_office.
    if ($_POST['onoff'] == 'ON'){

    $sql = "INSERT INTO b83hi_out_of_office (username, custommessage) VALUES ('$_POST[username]'.'$_POST[custommessage]')";
}
```

}

```
else{
   echo "Invalid Username";
}

?>
```

Like I said, I am just beginning. Everything makes sense when I think about the steps I need to take, but the code is not working. The main part I am stuck on is checking if the user exists. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

To check if user exists in database, you need to connect to the database first:

```
<?php 
$conn = mysqli_connect($hostname,$dbUsername,$dbPass,$dbName);

$checkQuery = SELECT * from b83hi_users WHERE username='$_POST[username]';

$userCheck = mysqli_query($conn, $checkQuery);

if(!$userCheck){
echo "Invalid Username";
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: I don't need to include the connect to database part since I am using sorcerer in Joomla, it automatically connects for me.

I tried this code but when I go to view the page on my website it is just plain white and blank. What causes this?

Comment: I edited the $checkQuery, I had made a mistake there. Try this again and let me know.

Comment: You need to add a semi colon to end of the $userCheck= line - I cannot make the edit as it needs to be 6 characters long and this is only 1 so it falls between the cracks...

Comment: Fixed it @bhttoanThanks for the heads up

Comment: @SabTheCoder I am still just getting a blank white page...
Also, I am wondering...the b83hi_ is the prefix for all the tables in my database, is it necessary to include it when naming the table in the code?